# Joomla from scratch

Tags: joomla1.5

I have joomla installed on my brothers server using softaculous in cpanel. But my brother removed all the categories, articles and sections on joomla that came with sample data. Now that i got access, i don't know how to do stuff without sample-data. I want to write things and continue with content management. But the problem is i have no knowledge of joomla. I don't know how i can write content for his site.

Is there any tutorial, guidance for starting joomla from scratch(that includes categories,menu,articles etc). I tried official visual help pdf. But got confused as there is no menu,articles and categories,section so it's tough to visualize in empty area in joomla.

Any help with steps to start with joomla from scratch ?

Comment: How about you install Joomla again?

Comment: I have to ? is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a high-level overview of Joomla's organizational structure:

The main body of any page is referred to as the **content**. At the deepest level, this would be a single **article** of content. Articles are organized within **categories** and each category is within a **section**. The content of a page can be set to a single category or section, showing teasers for all the articles within that container.

Elsewhere on the page can be little snippets of data called **modules** these encompass all other text that is not the main content. This includes footer text, a rss feed display, and the display of menu items.

Once content (articles) is created and organized on the administrative side, the navigation structure needs to be designed. Joomla has **menu** containers that contain **menu items**. Once you have a menu container created, you must create a module to tell Joomla where on the page to put it (most templates have various zones to place modules into, around the main content), so it will be displayed.

So, create a section, create a category in the section, and create an article in the category. Create a menu container, create a menu item in that container that points to the section. Create a module to show the menu container. Then you should have a basic site that has one menu option, that when clicked shows the categories in that section, and if you click the one category listed, will show the one article in that category, and when that article title is clicked, will show the article.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to buy a book, the "Joomla! 1.5: A User's Guide" by Barrie North will walk you through starting a site with Joomla from scratch.  This is what I recommend to all my newbie friends.